# Adding data labels to treemap chart

Tags: tableau-api, treemap

I have a treemap chart which contain age bins (under 18, 18-21 etc) and the number of customers as the size of the treemap's "boxes"
I want to add the number of customers as data label (e.g., there are 200 customers in the age of 18-21; I want the chart to present 200 as data label)..

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull in `Number of Records` to the Label box and you should have the count of customers displayed. If this doesn't display the count you are expecting, you may have to create a calculated field for distinct count of customers. The formula would be:

```
 COUNTD([customer])
```

Pull this field to the Label box and check.